# jquery slideToggle() not working with toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to slideToggle menu items with toggleclass, `.opened` class should be added and removed for menu items. This is working for me when I toggle  different menu item but for same menu item when I click this, `.opened` class won't get removed here is my code

Html menu tag

```
<ul id="menu-main-menu">
<li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">text<a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li class="menu-item">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">second sub item<a></li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">first sub item<a></li>
     <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">first sub item<a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">text<a></li>
</ul>
```

jquery code

```
$('.menu-item').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.menu-item').removeClass('opened')
    $(this).toggleClass('opened');
    if ($('.sub-menu', this).length >=1) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
    $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').hide('slow')
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can you please help me for this?
Thanks

Comment: toggle class is working fine for `<a href="link_url">text<a>`

Comment: please suggest me what can i do for this

Comment: have you linked jQuery

Comment: yes jquery have linked up

Comment: Have you got any errors in your console?

Comment: no console errors

Comment: paste your css too,

Comment: I think not need css for this, I only need open remove for slidetoogle

Comment: its okay, but what are you doing with class then

Comment: adding a + and - icons for open and close

Comment: The HTML code shown here has wrong closing anchor tags. `</a>`. Is that the case in the question here or in your code too?

Comment: no I have the html code tag fine in my end I have been typed the question here

Comment: `$('.menu-item').not($(this)).removeClass('opened');` You need to add this instead of removing from all the elements. You need to skip the current element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a basic mistake in your code.

1. Close Anchor tags, you have an opening anchor tag on both the ends.
2. then use the logic to get your result, see the example, If need anything else, please let me know
3. Add sub items Achor or li text, that depends on your requirement, but for UX you should add some text so users can get that there is still some more content to see.

```js
$('.menu-item').click(function(e){
        $(this).siblings().find('> .sub-menu').slideUp();
        $(this).find('> .sub-menu').slideToggle();
        $(this).siblings().removeClass('opened');
        $(this).toggleClass('opened');
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

```css
.sub-menu {
            display: none;
        }
        .menu-item a{
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            
        }
        .menu-item {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .menu-item.hasSubmenu {
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
        }
        .menu-item a {
            background-color: red;
            color: white;
        }
        .hasSubmenu {
            position: relative;
        }
        .hasSubmenu:after {
            position: absolute;
            right: 10px;
            top: 0px;
            content: "+";
            display: block;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .hasSubmenu.opened:after {
            content: "-";
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <ul id="menu-main-menu">
        <li class="menu-item hasSubmenu">
            <a href="link_url">text</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item hasSubmenu">
                    <a href="">First level</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">second sub item</a></li>
                         <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">second sub item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">first sub item</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">first sub item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item hasSubmenu">
            <a href="link_url">text</a>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li class="menu-item hasSubmenu">
                    <a href="">First level</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">second sub item</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">first sub item</a></li>
                <li class="menu-item"><a href="link_url">first sub item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: you are superv, you got my point gave the solution as prompted. Still have an issues the menu items are clicking and going to url. I want to prevent them to not go to url

Comment: But yes I have added the condition now this working well

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.menu-item').on('click', function(e) {

  $(this).toggleClass('opened');
  $('.menu-item').not($(this)).removeClass('opened');
  
  if ($('.sub-menu', this).length >= 1) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  $(this).children('ul').slideToggle('fast');
  $(this).siblings('li').find('ul').hide('slow')
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Change the order of removing classes, then skip the current element.